# NullPointer exception being thrown using .equals on string in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of "#" and "." I am Passing into a method, I am then trying to iterate through the array and find how many "#" are in it. I keep getting a NULLPOINTER exception when using .equals. the method should return the amount of "#" in the array. I tried iterating through the 2d Array and then converted the 2d into a single dimension array and still am getting the EXCEPTION Im not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
my code is:

public static int countSeats(String[][] aud){

```
   int openSeats = 0;

   String [] audit;
   audit = new String[120];

   int k = 0;
   for(int i= 0; i < aud.length; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < aud[i].length; j++)
           audit[k++] = aud[i][j];

    for(int i= 0; i <= audit.length; i++){   
       openSeats = audit[i].equals("#")? +1:+0;
    }
return openSeats;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an exception because of your loop condition:

```
for(int i= 0; i <= audit.length; i++){
```

Notice how you're using `<=` and not `<`. You're looping through the entire `audit` array, and then going one more than you should, resulting in the NullPointerException.

Comment: Even after changing the sign to <, the exception is still being thrown. The compiler seems to be pointing to openSeats = audit[i].equals("#")? +1:+0; I was pretty certain this was a solid way of checking the contents of an array. each iteration should be returning a string which should be compared with "#" using the .equals method, but i must be totally missing something.

Comment: If you want to increment the value either do `openSeats += audit[i].equals("#") ? 1 : 0;` or use an `if` and `openSeats++`. 

The NullPointer exception you're getting now is likely because `audit.length` is always 120, which is what you defined it as. You actually should check if `audit[i]` is null, since you will need to rely on that to know where your array ends. Otherwise you could use an ArrayList and not have to check for nulls yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you declare String[] audit, makes the solution even more complicated as you MAYBE TRY TO PUT ALL THE 2-D in 1-D thinking that it will simplify the problem for you, but it wont. Stay inside the 2-D, and do the search

```
   int openSeats = 0;
   for(int i= 0; i < aud.length; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < aud[i].length; j++)
       {
           if( aud[i][j].equals("#") )
           {
               openSeats++;
           }
       }
   }
   return openSeats;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are running your `for` loop one iteration extra by having `i <= audit.length;` instead of `i < audit.length;`. Also, as a good practice, always keep the String literal on the left side of the method call. E.g. instead of `aud[i][j].equals("#")`, do `"#".equals(aud[i][j])` to avoid any possibility of NPE.